# What are snakemake metadata files? When can I erase those?

Tags: snakemake

I notice that my backup rsync script spends quite some time copying stuff with random name from `.snakemake/metadata` folders.

What are those files used for?

Can I safely erase them after a snakemake run has completed, or are they necessary for snakemake to correctly perform the next run?

More generally, is there some documentation about the files that snakemake creates in the `.snakemake` folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [this comment by Johannes Koster](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/42/unneeded-snakemake-directory), creator of Snakemake:

> [The .snakemake/ directory] is used to track (a) the value of the
>   version keyword for each file, (b) the rule implementation for each
>   file, in order to notify the user if something has changed when
>   snakemake is invoked with --summary.

From a related [comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/snakemake/vGOWnLQqTj8/X8OU95jYBwAJ) on the Google Group:

> In general, it is safe to delete the entire .snakemake directory if
>   there is no running Snakemake instance and you are sure that all
>   existing output files are complete. It only contains data provenance
>   information (e.g., to track code input file or parameter changes [*to determine if the workflow should be re-run*]). You
>   might want to keep .snakemake/conda, since it contains the conda
>   environments used in your workflow.

Edit: To automatically remove the `.snakemake/` directory upon successful execution of the pipeline, the `onssuccess` hook can be used:

```py
import shutil
onsuccess:
    shutil.rmtree(".snakemake")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it work / be safe to put some cleaning code in `onsuccess` to remove some of the things in `.snakemake`?

Comment: I believe that should be ok as long as you don't care about state persistence. It would end up being something like:

```import shutil```; then ```onsuccess: shutil.rmtree(".snakemake")```. You could also chain it to your snakemake invocation: `snakemake --snakefile mysnakefile && rm -r ./.snakemake/`

Comment: but there is already a flag `[--cleanup-metadata FILE [FILE ...]] [--cleanup-shadow]` in [snakemake command line documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html?highlight=--cleanup-metadata%2F--cm)

Answer (score 1):

Old question now and not really answering it... Since you mention `rsync`, you can skip `.snakemake` directories with the `--exclude` option, like:

```
rsync ... --exclude='.snakemake' source/ dest/
```